# Springboot service using Websphere thinclient gets constant NMSV307E at startup, and finally fails in Websphere factorybean

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat, websphere, ejb

I maintain a platform used by a hundred or so SpringBoot (v2.7.11) services. Some of them call legacy EJBs running on a Websphere server.  The clients use the IBM Websphere Thinclient artifact (version 8.5.0).

Some of that subset of services get a number of the following warning immediately at startup:

> NMSV0307E: A java: URL name was used, but Naming was not configured to handle java: URL names. The likely cause is a user in error attempting to specify a java: URL name in a non-J2EE client or server environment. Throwing ConfigurationException.

In some of those cases, this causes the service startup to take at least an order of magnitude longer than necessary.  I was able to discover where this warning was coming from, which is `com.ibm.ws.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory.isNameSpaceAccessable()`. I set a breakpoint there and walked up the stack, but that didn't really help. It showed in the guts of Spring startup that it was trying to do something with PropertySources, and then it found a JNDIPropertySource, which led to this warning.  All of this obviously occurs outside the scope of an EJB call, the service is just starting up to prepare to take requests.

In a couple of these services, I found that after emitting hundreds of those warnings, it then said that Tomcat failed to start up, and it didn't give any reason.  I discovered that setting breakpoints in `org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext` wherever it sets "ok = false" would lead me to where it was failing. It hit one of those, and when I analyzed where it was failing, it led me to discover that this "thinclient" artifact jar encapsulates several different JEE packages that are also included in artifacts used by SpringBoot, and the packages provided by SpringBoot are newer than what comes in the thinclient jar.  I found that the "thinclient" was placed earlier in the classpath than those other artifacts, so it was getting the old packages.

Acknowledging that I don't know exactly what is going on here, I proceeded to produce a modified copy of that `thinclient` artifact, which I call `thinclient-minimized`, which omits several JEE packages that are duplicated in other artifacts pulled in by SpringBoot. I changed the pom.xml of that service to use the `thinclient-minimized` artifact.  In one service, that fixed the Tomcat startup problem.

I then discovered another service with similar problems.  Numerous NMSV307E warnings at startup, and then it finally failed in `org.springframework.jmx.support.WebSphereMBeanServerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()` because 'com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminServiceFactory.getMBeanFactory()`was returning NULL, resulting in an NPE. I stepped through the code in`com.ibm.websphere.management.AdminServiceFactory.getMBeanFactory()`, and it returns NULL because, and this is a guess, because the profilestack was empty (not sure what that means).

I tried changing this service to use the `thinclient-minimized` artifact, and it's possible that this reduced the number of NMSV307E warnings, but it didn't fix the final NPE.

Concerning the use of version 8.5.0 of the Thinclient artifact, I was told that we can't yet upgrade to version 9.0 because that won't be compatible with the Websphere server we connect to.

I could use some advice on how we can move forward here.